# Cursor cur = getall();

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The following code views all of the records in the database.

```
Cursor cur = db.getall(); 

adapter = new RRSelectTrackActivity.MyAdapter(this, cur, this, this);

public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, OnClickListener btnOnClick,OnCheckedChangeListener chkOnChange) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, c );
    this.btnOnClick = btnOnClick;
    this.chkOnChange = chkOnChange;
}
```

I only need to view the first three records.  How can I modify this code for that purpose?

Comment: Modify the query in `getall()` to `LIMIT 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line executes a query in the background and gets a cursor which lets you move through it one record at a time.  You should be interested in the function called in that line instead of the function you wrote to use the data.

```
Cursor cur = db.getall();
```

The method that calls the query is the `getall();` method on the `db` instance.  So, go to the `db` class definition and make another method named something like `getTopNRecords(int n)` that uses the same exact query as `getall()` except make the query start with `select top {n}` instead of simply `select`.

This way, your existing function that uses the data can remain the same, it just has to call a different function than `getall()` so that it is given less data to work with in the first place.

Some databases don't support the "select top" syntax.  In that case, you can usually add "limit {n}" to the query.

**Examples:**

```
select top 5 first_name, last_name from people;
select first_name, last_name from people limit 5;
```

Comment: `Some databases don't support the "select top" syntax.` What databases DO support this syntax? It definitely ins't standard SQL

Comment: Ingres and Vectorwise do.  I believe SQL server does as well.

Comment: First of all... yelling in caps does not help anything.  Secondly, you would have to add the function yourself before you called it, unless another similar one exists (and I'm assuming if it did you would have called it). If that's a little over your head you should probably read an intro-to-java book.